# hanging problem too much

Tags: 16.04, services, boot-time

What type of service I have to removed so that hanging problem is gone?

```
13.373s dev-sda1.device
          7.966s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.422s systemd-udevd.service
          5.688s grub-common.service
          5.648s irqbalance.service
          5.595s ondemand.service
          5.390s lightdm.service
          5.357s apport.service
          4.212s accounts-daemon.service
          4.132s ModemManager.service
          4.025s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          3.728s NetworkManager.service
          2.975s thermald.service
          1.656s keyboard-setup.service
          1.232s systemd-journald.service
          1.169s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.108s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.101s sys-kernel-debug.mount
          1.100s dev-hugepages.mount
          1.099s dev-mqueue.mount
           924ms apparmor.service
           759ms plymouth-start.service
           541ms ufw.service
           489ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           478ms udisks2.service
           400ms systemd-rfkill.service
           383ms systemd-sysctl.service
           366ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
           355ms polkitd.service
           317ms console-setup.service
           315ms avahi-daemon.service
           314ms systemd-logind.service
           293ms networking.service
           292ms gpu-manager.service
           289ms pppd-dns.service
           287ms ssh.service
           282ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           278ms rsyslog.service
           239ms upower.service
           190ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           144ms setvtrgb.service
           124ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4a8c3f60\x2d1884\x2d4b32\x2da561\x2dea49c08
           120ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           106ms snapd.socket
            91ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            81ms plymouth-read-write.service
            60ms binfmt-support.service
            52ms colord.service
            19ms user@1000.service
            18ms wpa_supplicant.service
            17ms alsa-restore.service
            13ms snapd.autoimport.service
             9ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             8ms dns-clean.service
             7ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
             7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             6ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
             6ms systemd-timesyncd.service
             5ms rc-local.service
             5ms systemd-random-seed.service
             4ms resolvconf.service
             4ms ureadahead-stop.service
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
             2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
lines 44-66/66 (END)
```

Comment: what type of service i have to removed so that hanging problem is gone....